# Excel Macro to force upper case and remove special characters with button click

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 codes but only one is working in VBA. I have

```
Private Sub FINALIZEBTN_Click()

Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
response = MsgBox("HAVE YOU COMPLETED THE FORM IN FULL?", vbYesNo)
If response = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "DO NOT FORGET TO SAVE AND SUBMIT THIS FORM"
    Else
If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "PLEASE REVIEW AND COMPLETE THE FORM IN FULL"
    Exit Sub
End If
End If

Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
        If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So on the click you get a yes/no prompt then it forces uppercase throughout the whole sheet.

The only symbols we are allowing are '&' and '-' 
I would either like another box to pop up when a special character is entered telling them something like "hey you can't do this" or when a special character is found to remove it and just remove it with nothing. If we could get it to remove and replace the latin letters with the acutes (like for spanish) that would also great. Currently I don't see any changes when I save or run the macros with the code in module 1.

I have the following code in Module 1

```
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSpecialChars = "\/:*?""<>|$,.`"
    For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), "")
    Next
    removeSpecial = sInput
End Function
```

Comment: This is a function, you must call it on your main procedure like this: `removeSpecial(YourTextOrStringVariableHere)`

Comment: So can I call it out on the

 ```Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
        If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)
    Next cell``` 
portion of the button code? If so where would it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you need to call the `removeSpecial`.

That said, I would rewrite `removeSpecial` to specify characters you want to keep, as there are many more special characters than what you have listed in `removeSpecial`

Other changes

- Use [SpecialCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) `xlCellTypeConstants` to only loop over cells containing values (removes need to test `Len` and excludes formulas).
- Account for possibility sheet has no constant values
- Added substitution of accented characters: you will need to extend the `ReplaceFrom` and `ReplaceWith` strings to include all replacements you want (make sure these two strings are the same length)
- You may (or may not) want to include other characters in the inclusion, eg space, or other punctuation?  If so, add them to the `sKeepChars` [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008961)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) pattern (leave the `-` as the first character inside then `[]`
- ALL CAPS messages are ugly!

---

```
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sKeepChars As String
    Dim sClean As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const ReplaceFrom As String = "AE"
    Const ReplaceWith As String = "ÀÊ"

    sKeepChars = "[-&A-Z" & ReplaceWith & "]"
    For i = 1 To Len(sInput)
        c = Mid$(sInput, i, 1)
        If c Like sKeepChars Then
            j = InStr(ReplaceFrom, c)
            If j Then
                c = Mid$(ReplaceWith, j, 1)
            End If
            sClean = sClean & c
        End If
    Next
    removeSpecial = sClean
End Function


Private Sub FINALIZEBTN_Click()
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Have you completed the form in full?", vbYesNo)
    If response = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Do not forget to save and submit this form"
    ElseIf response = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Please review and complete the form in full"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In rng
                cell = removeSpecial(UCase(cell))
            Next cell
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: any idea on how to get this to keep the spaces in everything? When  i ran this code it pulled all of the spaces on everything in the whole entire file.

Comment: Wow, if that was a snake it would have bitten me.. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine:

```
    Dim MyStr As String
    For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
        If Len(cell) > 0 Then
            MyStr = cell
            cell = UCase(removeSpecial(MyStr))
        End If
    Next cell
```

Comment: The first one didn't do anything. The second one is giving me a `Compile Error: ByRef argument type mismatch` and its flagging the `cell=removepecial(cell)` portion

Comment: Hmm... Try to give it `cell.value` or `cell.text`

Comment: so close, now were getting an runtime 424 object required error

Comment: Then, declare a variable called... `MyStr as String` then give  `MyStr`the `cell.value` and call the function with `MyStr` to finally `cell = MyStr`

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm not following this.. is there any way that you can break it down for me a little?

Comment: I've edited my answer @EmilyStrzelecki now it shouldn't give any problem

Comment: `Private Sub FINALIZEBTN_Click()

Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
response = MsgBox("HAVE YOU COMPLETED THE FORM IN FULL?", vbYesNo)
If response = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "DO NOT FORGET TO SAVE AND SUBMIT THIS FORM"
    Else
If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "PLEASE REVIEW AND COMPLETE THE FORM IN FULL"
    Exit Sub
End If
End If
Dim MyStr As String
For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
    If Len(cell) > 0 Then
        MyStr = removeSpecial(cell.Value)
        cell = UCase(MyStr)
    End If
Next cell
End Sub`

Comment: module 1 has ```Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSpecialChars = "\/:*?""<>|$,.`"
    For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), "")
    Next
    removeSpecial = sInput
End Function```

the uppercase is running but the symbols are still there.

Comment: I've tested this last edit on my answer and it works. But not the way you want I guess... it's only keeping the characters you gave it. Which are: `[-&A-ZÀÊ]`